# What is the best way to serve images folder? Express server

Tags: express, server, multer

I made an admin panel for a website.

Admin upload data and images to server using multer.

Then I want to serve those images to front-end. Serving as static files made download image instead of displaying, so url doesnt show anything in html.

I found a solution but I dont think is the correct one. Because is a bit slow.

Info:

Size of each image: 2-3 MB.

Public side in PHP -> Takes 15 seconds per image

Admin side front end in vue js -> takes 6 seconds per image, 50 seconds to load
20 images

Api in express server Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64
Size
1 vCPUs
2GB / 25GB Disk

Solution :

```
router.get('/photos', async (req,res) => {
    let path = req.query.path;
    path = `../../uploads/${path}`
    if(path){
        fs.readFile(resolve(__dirname, path), function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");    
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'image/jpg'});
                res.end(content);
            }
        });
    }
})`
```

Comment: How slow is it? When serving what size of image, from what server, to what client, rendered in which browser? How fast do you expect it to be instead?

Comment: @underscore_d edited. the browser is chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve a folder as -

Add the following to you `app.js` file for express. Here, the folder `my_images` exists on the same level as `app.js` in your project.

```
app.use(
  "/photos",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "my_images/"))
)
```

Check out the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: I tried this and when I go to url  browser automatic download img instead of display. Is it essential exist in same level as app.js?

Comment: You need to send a request to `/photos` from the frontend to fetch the contents of these images. You can use `fetch()` from javascript or a library like `axios` for this. If you directly go to the above URL from a browser, then the images will be downloaded to your computer because that's what you're asking it to do. A request is sent to the server and the response from it is downloaded.